# How to change og meta tags dynamically on Sapper.js project

Tags: svelte, strapi, sapper, svelte-3, facebook-debugger

I am working on a Sapper.js with Strapi blog. I want to use share social buttons for sharing each blog post. Do you know how can i change the og meta tags dynamically as each blog post would take his photo and title. I tried with svelte:head  but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`<svelte:head>` is the way to do this. It should be as simple as setting up the meta tags inside.

Can you see the tags in the source code when you inspect it? Have you checked if the tags are being rendered on the server? Does it work if you hard-code the values?

Comment: I tried this, but <svelte:head> renders the meta tags after the page is loaded and i get this following warning from facebook developer: The ‘og:image’ property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. The hydration of og meta tags should be done before the page rendering, i guess.

Comment: And to answer your questions: Yes, i see the dynamically meta tags correct after inspect. i hardcoded the values. And for the second question, they are rendered client side. I think that is the solution, to render them on the server, but i don't know how. should i use polka/express for that?

Comment: No you should simply be able to use svelte:head as usual in Sapper. Do you have the data when it runs the SSR or are you fetching it in onMount or something like that? I've used OG tags myself in Sapper and I have not had a problem like this.

Comment: Data is fetched in <script context="module">. And then is passed to svelte:head meta tags. I get this error on facebook debugger: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: I think i may do something wrong, but i don't know what, because the new meta tags are shown after inspect.

Comment: Can you show me some code from your example, please? thanks a lot

Comment: I have the same issue for my blog here => https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/use-useref-hook-to-store-values-you-want-to-keep-an-eye-on I see correct meta tags in the browser or even twitter validator but Facebook and Linkedin validators throw an error about missing og:image If you inspect the code underneath there is one. Any ideas maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svelte:head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <!-- open graph (og) SEO  -->
    <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
    <meta property="og:image" content={coverImageUrl} />
</svelte:head>
```